# How can py tuple implicit cast to int?

Tags: python, hash, tuples

I have some code that for a grid of ints requires comparing cols with rows.  The grid dimension is unknown at compile time.

So I need a good hash function for a 1-d array of int.

The following code compiles and runs as expected as it uniquely identifies any row or col :

```
def hashValue(a: List[int]) -> int:
    return tuple(a)

rows = {}
for i in range(len(grid)):
    hash = hashValue(grid[i])
    if hash in rows:
        rows[hash] += 1
    else:
        rows.append(hash,1)
```

But I don't understand what's going on under the hood.

The hash function creates a tuple from the List[int] and returns an int where it properly serves as a key in the dictionary of rows with which cols are compared later on.

But how is py converting the tuple to an int ?

Does py maintain an internal hash of the immutable tuple ?

Comment: This does not, in fact, work as a hash. You must have misunderstood something.

Comment: `tuple`, `frozenset`, `str` are example of hashable containers and all of them have an implementation of the method `__hash__`

Comment: What does *"works fine as a hash "* mean?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking and the typing the code is very confusing since it does not return and int. The only thing going on under the hood of this code is converting a list to a tuple and an incorrect return type. Maybe you could add a little more code that show what you mean by "works fine".

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "works fine as a hash". Tuple objects are *hashable* (so they can be contained by hash-based containers, like `set` or `dict`). Many different objects are hashable, and you can defined your own hashable types. You need to explain a bit.more about what exactly you are doing and what exactly you were expecting. There is no implicit "casting" going on anywhere, it is unclear if you are referring to the incorrect return type annotation or what